# Query on three tables with an id projection

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

I have a table X : Id,Name
I have a table Y : Id,Name,X_Id
I have a table Z : Id,Y_id

How can i perform a criteria query or a HQL query that would return 
all Z objects ids that are linked to an X object.

(in my case, X is a Conversation Space, Y are Conversations, and Z are categories)

HBM :

The Conversation object has the following mapping for categories :

```
<set name="allCatIdSet" table="CATEGORIES"  lazy="true">
      <cache usage="read-write" />
      <key>
        <column name="ITEM_ID" index="MY INDEX"/>
      </key>
      <element type="string">
        <column name="VALUE" length="64" index="MY INDEX"/>
      </element>      
</set>
```

And a foreign key for Conversation Space id :

```
<property name="conversationSpaceId" length="64" index="CONVSPACEINDEX"/>
```

Comment: What are the associations between the entities? What have you tried? This is really basic.

Answer (score 1):

Short question, short answer:

```
public List<Z> findZbyX(X x) { 
  // query Z objects 
  String hql = "FROM Z z WHERE z.y.x = :x"
  Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
  query.setParameter("x", x);
  return query.list();
}
```

This would return a list of Z objects, if you really just need a list of IDs of Zs change your HQL to `SELECT z.id FROM Z z WHERE z.y.x = :x`.